# Meaning of かな for asking questions

Tags: questions, sentence-final-particles

I'm reading Yotsubato to learn Japanese. On page 98 of Tome 1, Asagi asks Yotsuba:

> クーラーって　知ってるかなー？

I understand she's asking if Yotsuba knows what an air conditioner is, but I'm unsure about the nuance brought by the use of か and なー here.

From [Tae Kim's guide](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/question),

> The question marker 「か」 is usually not used with casual speech to make
>   actual questions. It is often used to consider whether something is
>   true or not. Depending on the context and intonation, it can also be
>   used to make rhetorical questions or to express sarcasm. It can sound
>   quite rough so you might want to be careful about using 「か」 for
>   questions in the plain casual form.

So which is it here? It doesn't seem like she's trying to sound rough or sarcastic.

Also, is なー　here just a way of saying な, itself just a way of saying ね (I'm still quite confused with all the sentence-ending particles)? What would be overall an accurate translation of the question?

Comment: More context: よつば enters a room. 「このへやつめたいぞ！」「つめたい？クーラー効きすぎ？」「！？ここは冬か？」「そんなに寒いかな？よつばちゃん冷え性？」「さ　さむくない……えっと…　ちょうどさむい！」「……もしかして」(points at AC device)「クーラーって知ってるかなー？この機械なんだけど」「なんだ、それは！」(lifts Yotsuba to AC blast)「それ」「おー！つめたかぜがでてくる！なんだこれは？」「クーラーよ　クーラー。夏でもすずしくしてしまう機械よ」「おおー　すっげぇー！」

Comment: Anyway, you're missing the もしかして in the question. It changes the tone quite a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From WWWJDIC:

> かな ； かなあ
>
> 1. [prt] 
>      ▶ (at sentence end) I wonder
> 2. [prt] 
>      ▶ (at sentence end) should I?
>      ▶ is it?
> 3. [prt] 
>      ▶ (at sentence end) I wish that (with a negative)
>      ▶ I hope that

In this context, かな functions as "I wonder...?"

知ってるかなー？ would translate as "I wonder if you know (about)?" It's a more indirect way to ask than 知ってるか？

As you mentioned, か is used to designate a question. 
な (or なあ, なー, etc) can be used at the end of sentences to colloquially indicate wondering.

> そう思っていたなー？ - That's what you thought, huh?

As opposed to

> そう思っていた. - That's what you thought.

Definition Source: WWWJDIC at http://wwwjdic.com