# Meaning of かな in this context?

Tags: meaning

Among several other meanings, かな is usually translated as "I wonder", but what does it mean in the following conversation?

> A: 「僕はジャズが大好き！君は？」
>
> B: 「私もジャズが**好きかな**。」

Is the speaker uncertain about whether she likes Jazz or not? Or is it a polite way of saying something on the lines of, e.g, あまり好きじゃない, 嫌いじゃない, and so on?

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/37001/7810

Comment: @broken headphones That question mentions かな only in the sense of "I wonder", but there are many other meanings to it; I'm sure one of these other meanings apply in this case, although I'm not sure which.

Answer (score 3):

It means more like "I guess". Say that a person who isn't very into music gets asked what his favorite genre is, then he might reply:

```
Maybe Jazz, I guess...
```

So it does add some kind of uncertainty to the reply, and why the speaker is uncertain can depend on a lot of different reasons, just like in any language.

Comment: Even in a conversation going like "A: 僕はジャズが大好き    B: 私もジャズが好きかな"?