# What does どうしてこのサイトに来てるのかな？

Tags: meaning, words, phrases

My question is why is かな being used in this sentence? The person is asking me why I come/came to he site? or wondering why I came to the site? Would かな be added after the の? I am used  to seeing かな used in statements not questions.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/37001/32952

Answer (score 3, accepted):

かな at the end of a question sentence ending with の is a bit of a reflexive ending that provides the nuance of wondering about what is being asked.

Consider, then:

> どうしてこのサイトに来てるの？
>   Why did you come to this site?

vs.

> どうしてこのサイトに来てるのかな？
>   I wonder why you have come to this site.

Comment: Isn't the nuance more along the lines of "why you come to this site" (regularly) as opposed to "why you have come to this site" (this once)?

Comment: @By137 Because of 来てる (or 来ている), it looks like the question is about why they are there right that moment, as opposed to just 来る which would point to a more habitual action